# IOS - Array created in async returning only one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, asynchronous

I'm really having trouble figuring this out.  I'm parsing JSON into an array asynchronously.  Running NSLog on the async function prints out an array with multiple objects, which is what I want.  But when I run the NSLog on the returned array in the ViewController it only prints out the last object of the array.  I then run a count on it and there is, in fact, only 1 object in the array.  Why is it only returning an array with one object from an array with multiple objects?  Below is my code.  Thanks for any input you might have.

**Function performed asynchronously**

```
- (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *allTeams = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:data
                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                   error:&error];

if( error )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    team = allTeams[@"10"];
    for ( NSDictionary *teamArray in team )
    {
        teams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: teamArray[@"team"], nil];

}
}

return teams;
}
```

**ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"teams" withExtension:@"json"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    teams = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];

    int i = [teams count];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);

});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add object to the existing array instead of reinitalizing it everytime

```
    teams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: teamArray[@"team"], nil];
```

should be

```
else {
    team = allTeams[@"10"];
    teams = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for ( NSDictionary *teamArray in team )
    {
        [teams addObject:teamArray[@"team"]];

}
```

Also you are sending synchronous request using this code

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

you should use the `sendAsynchronous` methods. Synchronous request can be terminated by the OS itself and can lead to some confusion and bugs later on